# MODX Formit dynamic mail address in the hook "emailTo"

Tags: email, hook, modx, formit

I've created a site with 30 providers of workshops. Each provider has its own contact form. I now have a separate template for each provider. The hook "emailto" is, in fact, the only variable in the template. I would like to have one template, and specify via TV the `mailaddress` that Formit should use.

I have tried it with `` &emailTo=`[[+mailaddress]]` `` and `` &emailTo=`[[+tv.mailadres]]` `` but unfortunately without result.
Can it be done? And if so, how?

Comment: why the placeholder? [+] is this being called via getresources or a custom snippet??  If it's just in a template treat the TV like any other page variable...  [[*mailaddress]]

Comment: thanks. In the rtfm about email hooks, I saw an example with a placeholder. That put me on the wrong track. Life can be easy :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I still have a problem. When I use a mailadres that belongs to the site /domain, it works fine. Any other mailadres (e.g. gmail.com or one of my own mailadresses) fails. Processing the form seems to be ok. After submitting I get the redirectpage. But I don't receive the form in my mailbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If the email address is saved in the template variable 'mailaddress' on each provider resource, you have to call FormIt with

```
&emailTo=`[[*mailaddress]]`
```

Comment: thanks. In the rtfm about email hooks, I saw an example with a placeholder. That put me on the wrong track. Life can be easy :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I still have a problem. When I use a mailadres that belongs to the site /domain, it works fine. Any other mailadres (e.g. gmail.com or one of my own mailadresses) fails. Processing the form seems to be ok. After submitting I get the redirectpage. But I don't receive the form in my mailbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you get to the redirect page and the email hook is called before the redirect hook, the mail must have been sent. So it has to be a spam filter on the receiving side.